# How to get height and width of WidgetKit widgets?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

I'm making an app where the user can select different widgets from a list. The list is implemented in a collectionView, after which a DetailView opens in which I want to show a preview of the widget. But I don't know how to implement it. The simplest thing is to make a UIView that copies the widget, but for this **I need to know the size of the widgets**, I know that there are only three of them and they are fixed, but I don't understand **how to get them**. Maybe you can somehow embed the widget itself in the DetailView, if you implement it in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SwiftUI, you can use `GeometryReader` to get the dimensions of the widgets.

Example usage:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
           //You now have access to geo.size.width and geo.size.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it shows zero, I mean when I print it as print(geo.size.width)